# Looking for an online course

Tags: self-learning

My friend and I are interesting in doing an online math course together. He has the basic high school math up to Calculus AB and will be doing BC while we are doing the course. I, however have done Calculus III, Differentiate Equations and Linear Algebra already. Could someone please recommend an online courses in an area other than those three which would be accessible with my friend's background?

Comment: a free course or a paid course? do you want to get any credits for it?

Comment: Either would be be ok, wouldn't mind not getting credit

Comment: I am biased, but I would recommend a discrete math or proof writing course if either of you have not yet had a formal introduction to that topic (especially as it will be highly useful to CS or Math majors later on).  If you have seen proofs well enough, then look into Graph Theory or Combinatorics, as they can be rather fun and rewarding.  They are also both quite different in flavor to calculus, and little to no calculus is required (a few calculations with limits or infinite series on occasion).

Comment: [ocw.mit.edu](http://ocw.mit.edu) has interesting courses (you can see which ones have video lectures), you could take some quantum physics even if you like, which is quite fun.
[Stat 110: probability at Harvard](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2SOU6wwxB0uwwH80KTQ6ht66KWxbzTIo) a series of online lectures, no course notes though I guess, a nice introduction to probability as needed for statisticians (also covers a little bit of Markov Chains), more in depth as in high school. For paid courses, see [edx.org](https://www.edx.org/).

Comment: edx is very interesting, although I am not sure whether you can see all lessons one after an other, I think you get some sort of a schedule to which you need to adhere and the lectures get streamed during a semester or time period, but in many cases you can go for a certificate if you like. ocw has the advantage that you can view all lessons one after an other.

Comment: I tend to agree with @JMoravitz, any proof writing course seems useful if you are not used to it.

Answer (score 3):

Please do check Coursera and EDX.

https://www.edx.org/

https://www.coursera.org/